# How to add a navigation controller to a UIViewController that's not the initial UIViewController

Tags: swift, swift4

Alright, I hope the title of this question made sense. Basically, I have an app that has a login screen and once you log in it takes you to another view controller. The login screen is set as the initial view controller and it doesn't have a navigation controller since I wouldn't want the user going back to that screen unless they log out. So, I added a navigation controller through storyboard to my mainViewController which is the controller that gets presented after logging in. The navigation controller is not showing up though. I'm not sure if it has to do with the way I'm presenting the mainViewController but I'll show you my code and I'll let you be the judge!

[StoryBoard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnGRm.png)

```
let pushedViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController") as! mainViewController
self.present(pushedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I never added any additional code to my AppDelegate class, so I'm not sure if I have to do something there?

Comment: Yes, You are right. You need to add a UserDefault in AppDelegate class to check logged in User. Then add conditional statement to push to Login screen or not.

Comment: @PiyushMathur So I didn't have to set root view controller as my nav, but the answer below worked because I'm dumb and forgot to add my storyboard identifier. Thank you for your answer because this worked as well! Also, I don't understand why my question got down voted. Could you provide feedback on why if you down voted my question?

Comment: That wasn't me. But downvotes are given when the question is duplicated; when the question is not clear. So I would like to advice u to search for the answers first for the questions identical to yours.

Comment: @PiyushMathur Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking navigation controller from storyboard, then present the navigation controller not `mainViewController`.

**For that:**

You can assign identifier to navigationController as `"mainViewControllerNav"` and then update your code as:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewControllerNav")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now you are presenting the navigation controller and navigation controller will load its first viewcontroller in stack which is your `"mainViewController"`.

**Rather:**

I will suggest you to change the root on logging in and logging out as:

```
if let navVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewControllerNav") as? UINavigationController,
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navVC
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I'm so dumb...I had this before but forgot to use the storyboard identifier....Also, I don't understand why my question got down voted. Could you provide feedback on why if you down voted my question?

Comment: @MikeKoofer, Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically by setting `rootViewController` in a UINavigationController`

```
let pushedViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController") as! mainViewController
let vc = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: pushedViewController)
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: So I didn't have to set root view controller as my nav, but the answer above worked because I'm dumb and forgot to add my storyboard identifier. Thank you for your answer because this worked as well! Also, I don't understand why my question got down voted. Could you provide feedback on why if you down voted my question?

Comment: I wasn't the one down voting and i can't really see why it was down voted... maybe someone who doesn't like the fact that it gives the feeling of a wall of text without any highlighted key components.